# AWS Lambda image/pdf upload to S3 is corrupted (asp.net core)

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, asp.net-core-3.1

I have written a function that uploads a file in an s3 bucket. It works fine when I run my application locally.

But when I deploy the application in AWS Lambda, file upload is working properly but the file is being corrupted. The uploaded file size is a little bit higher than the actual file size.

txt file upload is working fine.

Here is my code

```
                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(logo.FileName);
                var fileName = $"{guid}{extension}";
                using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    logo.CopyTo(ms);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    System.IO.Stream stream = ms;
                    var client = new AmazonS3Client(AppConstants.S3AccessKey, AppConstants.S3SecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
                    PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = AppConstants.S3Bucket,
                        Key = fileName,
                        InputStream = stream
                    };

                    PutObjectResponse response = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);
                }
```

I have configure [API Gateway for binary data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html) as well as change the LambdaEntryPoint with following code

```
 RegisterResponseContentEncodingForContentType("multipart/form-data", ResponseContentEncoding.Base64);
```

Is there any other configuration that I missed?

Comment: As far as I remember AWS suggests using pre-signed URL's for this kind of operations. Can't you use them ? Also, base64 might be corrupted too, maybe adding a binary media type */* to gateway can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not showing the full code you have written. I had the same issue yesterday.

I was using the `System.Drawing.Image` namespace to store the image and then I was resizing it. The problem with the `System.Drawing.Image` is that it is supported only on the Windows platform. That's why it was working from the local machine.

This is how I have solved this issue:
I had to install a third-party library called [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp). The code is written below:

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Png;
public class Function
{
 public MemoryStream GetReducedImage(int width, int height, MemoryStream resourceImage)
 {
    try
    {
        using (var image = Image.Load(resourceImage))
        {
            image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, new PngEncoder());
            ms.Position = 0;
            return ms;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```